# How can I force the spelling mode in Dragon NaturallySpeaking to only recognize the NATO phonetic alphabet?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-recognition

Is there any way to configure Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that the spelling mode only recognizes the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) to dictate alphanumeric characters?